# Python overwriting variables in nested functions

Tags: python, scope

Suppose I have the following python code:

```
def outer():
    string = ""
    def inner():
        string = "String was changed by a nested function!"
    inner()
    return string
```

I want a call to outer() to return "String was changed by a nested function!", but I get "". I conclude that Python thinks that the line `string = "string was changed by a nested function!"` is a declaration of a new variable local to inner(). My question is: how do I tell Python that it should use the outer() string? I can't use the `global` keyword, because the string isn't global, it just lives in an outer scope. Ideas?

Comment: Might be related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/146359/212218

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you can use the [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) keyword:

```
def outer():
    string = ""
    def inner():
        nonlocal string
        string = "String was changed by a nested function!"
    inner()
    return string
```

In Python 2.x, you could use a list with a single element and overwrite that single element:

```
def outer():
    string = [""]
    def inner():
        string[0] = "String was changed by a nested function!"
    inner()
    return string[0]
```

Comment: +1 As for why the latter works: Item assignment (along with attribute assignment) is not variable assignment - `x[...] = ...` just gets `x` from whatever scope it would be in anyway, and call's its `__setitem__` method. An equally valid, but initially more verbose option is creating an object (of a user-defined class, as `object()` won't allow adding attributes) whose sole purpose is holding an attribute.

Comment: You can create such an "namespace object" using `x = type("", (), {})()`. :)

Comment: So, `nonlocal` means: "look for this variable in the outer scope" - if  the variable was not found in the outer() scope, would Python keep looking in enclosing scopes? Would Python eventually try to find the variable in the global scope?

Comment: Also, is there really NO way to rebind the outer() string in Python 2.x? It seems silly that I would have access a variable defined in an outer scope, and be able to call its methods, but not to reassign the variable to point to something else...

Comment: @Ord: `nonlocal` will look in all enclosing scopes except for the global scope -- that's what `global` is for after all.  There is no other way than the above solutions in Python 2.x -- that's why `nonlocal` was introduced.  And Python semantics say that assignment inside a function automatically makes a variable local to that function -- that's a sensible choice given that you don't declare variables in Python and the compiler somehow has to figure out the scope of a variable.

Comment: In 2.x, use a `dict` instead of a `list` if you want to access+modify multiple nonlocal variables *and* keep your code fairly clean.

Answer (score 28):

You can also get around this by using function attributes:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        inner.string = "String was changed by a nested function!"
    inner.string = ""
    inner()
    return inner.string
```

Clarification: this works in both python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

This happens to me way too often, when I was writing a function and I suddenly realize that it could be a good idea to have a smaller helper function, but not really useful anywhere else. which naturally makes me want to define it inside as a nested function.

but I had experience with JAVA anonymous object(ie: define a runnable), and the rule was that the anonymous object makes a hard copy of its outer environment, in this case variables of the outer scope. Thus if the outer variable is a immutable (`int`,`char`), they can not be modified by anonymous object as they are copied by **value** whereas if its a mutable (`collection`, `objects`), they can be changed...since they are copied by "**pointer**" (their address in memory)

if you know about programming, think of it as pass by value and pass by reference.

in python, it's very much the same. `x=123` is an assignment, they give the variable x a new meaning (not modify the old x), `list[i]/dict[key]` are object access operations, they really **modify** things

to conclude, you need a mutable object...in order to modify (even though you can access a tuple using [], you can not use it here since its not mutable)

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935984/703233):

In Python 2.x, you can only **read** outer scope variables from the inner scope. Assigning will just create a new local (i.e. inner scope) variable that hides the outer scope one.

If you want to **read and modify**, you can use a `dict` to hold your variables in the outer scope, and then access them via the dict in the inner scope, also keeping your code fairly **clean and readable** in the presence of **multiple** outer scope vars:

```
def outer():
    # hold some text, plus the number of spaces in the text
    vars = {'text': 'Some text.', 'num_spaces': 1}
    def inner():
        # add some more text
        more_text = ' Then some more text.'
        vars['text'] += more_text
        # keep track of the number of spaces
        vars['num_spaces'] += more_text.count(' ')
    inner()
    return vars['text'], vars['num_spaces']
```

output:

```
>>> outer()
('Some text. Then some more text.', 5)
```