# Function not changing global variable

Tags: python, global-variables

my code is as follow:

```
done = False

def function():
    for loop:
        code
        if not comply:
            done = True  #let's say that the code enters this if-statement

while done == False:
    function()
```

For some reason when my code enters the if statement, it doesn't exit the while loop after it's done with function().

BUT, if I code it like this:

```
done = False

while done == False:
    for loop:
    code
    if not comply:
        done = True  #let's say that the code enters this if-statement
```

...it exits the while loop. What's going on here?

I made sure that my code enters the if-statement. I haven't run the debugger yet because my code has a lot of loops (pretty big 2D array) and I gave up on debugging due to it being so tedious. How come "done" isn't being changed when it's in a function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python overwriting variables in nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935966/python-overwriting-variables-in-nested-functions)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your issue is that functions create their own namespace, which means that `done` within the function is a different one than `done` in the second example.  Use `global done` to use the first `done` instead of creating a new one.

```
def function():
    global done
    for loop:
        code
        if not comply:
            done = True
```

An explanation of how to use `global` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146557/do-you-use-the-global-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

```
done=False
def function():
    global done
    for loop:
        code
        if not comply:
            done = True
```

you need to use the global keyword to let the interpreter know that you refer to the global variable `done`, otherwise it's going to create a different one who can only be read in the function.

Answer (score 7):

Use `global`, only then you can modify a global variable otherwise a statement like `done = True` inside the function will declare a new local variable named `done`:

```
done = False
def function():
    global done
    for loop:
        code
        if not comply:
            done = True
```

Read more about [the global statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#global).

Answer (score 2):

#### Using a `class` rather than `global`:

Another way to handle (not use) global variables is to wrap the functions and variables you wish to be global in a **class**.

While this is a little heavy for this specific case - classes add a host of functionality and flexability to the project. (Personally) highly recommended.

#### For example:

```
class Processor():
    """Class container for processing stuff."""

    _done = False

    def function(self):
        """A function which processes stuff."""
        # Some code here ...
        self._done = True

# See the flag changing.
proc = Processor()
print('Processing complete:', proc._done)
proc.function()
print('Processing complete:', proc._done)
```

#### Output:

```
Processing complete: False
Processing complete: True
```