# Taking input from the user in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Goal:

1. Give the user a text field.
2. Print the text that he entered in the field once he presses a button below it into the shell.

How is this possible using Tkinter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We will take the text from the user using the `Entry` widget. And then we will define a function that will extract the text from this widget and print it out in the shell.

```
def printtext():
    global e
    string = e.get() 
    print string   

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root,text='okay',command=printtext)
b.pack(side='bottom')
root.mainloop()
```

The window instance is first created. And then an `Entry` widget is packed. After that another button widget is also packed. The `focus_set` method makes sure that the keyboard focus is on the text field when this is run. When the button is pressed it will go to the function which will extract the text from the `Entry` widget using the `get` method.

You can find more about the `Entry` widget and its methods here:

[Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: why are you declaring `global e`? As `e` was defined outside the function, it's already global, right?

Comment: @Hartnäckig [Aah, this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665994/function-not-changing-global-variable)

Comment: The link is broken. Maybe you should update it.

Answer (score -2):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("lol")
root.geometry("400x400")

input = Entry(root)
input.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality. Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.