# How do I display a dialog that asks the user multi-choice question using tkInter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Anyway, I've been searching around for a tkinter function that asks the user a multi-choice question, the closest thing I've found is messagebox.asknoyes, but it only offers 2 choice, furthermore I can't edit the choices as they are fixed (Yes or No), is there's a tkinter function that does what i'm looking for?

Note: this is not a possible duplicate of [Taking input from the user in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495559) as that question asks how to take input from the user, so the user can submit any input they want, while I want to give the user some predefined choice to choose one

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function for that. I think you're going to have to manually create a window, manually add radio buttons and labels to it, wait for the user to respond, and then manually check which radio button was selected.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you, please make this an answer so that I may accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking input from the user in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495559/taking-input-from-the-user-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Anil_M Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function for that. I think you're going to have to manually create a window, manually add radio buttons and labels to it, wait for the user to respond, and then manually check which radio button was selected.

Fortunately this is pretty straightforward, so I made a quick implementation for you.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Radiobutton, IntVar
#    ^ Use capital T here if using Python 2.7

def ask_multiple_choice_question(prompt, options):
    root = Tk()
    if prompt:
        Label(root, text=prompt).pack()
    v = IntVar()
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        Radiobutton(root, text=option, variable=v, value=i).pack(anchor="w")
    Button(text="Submit", command=root.destroy).pack()
    root.mainloop()
    if v.get() == 0: return None
    return options[v.get()]

result = ask_multiple_choice_question(
    "What is your favorite color?",
    [
        "Blue!",
        "No -- Yellow!",
        "Aaaaargh!"
    ]
)

print("User's response was: {}".format(repr(result)))
```