# How to ask the user a multi-choice Q in a function

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, python-3.6

This is basically the same as
[How do I display a dialog that asks the user multi-choice questıon using tkInter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581016/how-do-i-display-a-dialog-that-asks-the-user-multi-choice-quest%c4%b1on-using-tkinter)
Except I want to make it work it inside a function, here is the flaw with the accepted answer that I could not bypass:

1. The accepted answer doesn't work inside a function (It has problems with retrieving the input, ending the tkinter.Tk and displaying the radiobuttons)

So how do I implement a variation of a multi-choice-question dialog using tkinter that can work inside functions?

I have been stuck on this for a week

Comment: could we see some code or what you've tried?

Comment: is this function part of an existing tkinter program, or is this for a mostly non-gui program where you need to pop up just this one dialog?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, it is part of an existing tkinter program