# How to check if the random word is the same as the user input?

Tags: python, random, input

I am a beginner and I'm trying to write basic program that should check if the user input (entry) matches with the random word shown (a), or not. If it matches, it should give a new word and the typing field should be cleared.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
import random
import requests
import Tkinter
import requests
from Tkinter import *

point = 0

word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
a = random.choice(WORDS)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Stopwatch")
root.minsize(width=900, height=600)
root.configure(background='white')

e1 = Entry(root , justify='center')
e1.place(anchor=CENTER , bordermode=OUTSIDE)
e1.config(bg="white" , font="Geneva 30 bold")
e1.pack(expand=False, padx=20 , pady=20, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

label = Tkinter.Label(root, text = "Write this word: " + a , bg="white" , font="Geneva 30 bold")
label.pack()

if e1 == a: #virker ikke!
    print "correct"
    e1.delete(0, END)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only the line marked "virker ikke!" then it is because you are comparing a string value (a) with a tkinter.Entry instance.

Use the "get" method to get the current text from the entry:

```
if e1.get() == a:
  print("correct")
  e1.delete(0, END)
```

Secondly, I think you have the wrong idea about how UI toolkits typically work.

You create a text entry instance and display it correctly. But then, *immediately* after that, you check the value and you only check it once.

Instead you need to setup some signal handling. For example: set a callback to be called when the text in the entry changes, or add a button and attach the same callback to its click event.

Also, you need to let the program enter the main loop before you can expect *any* input in the entry.

Please note that I'm no expert at tkinter so this is only the general idea.

Comment: thank you, I have just tried replacing that part with your code, however it still does not work :(

Comment: i've updated the answer with some more general ideas

Answer (score 0):

If both are strings you can use the == operator, like follow:

```
a == b
```

Note that this is case-sensitive, if you want it to be case-unsensitive you can use the .lower() function of strings:

```
a.lower() == b.lower()
```

If they are not Strings, you can probably cast them to string.

Comment: how could I make the user input to the Entry field into a string though?

Comment: @BenceSzabó This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495559/taking-input-from-the-user-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
import random

def random_word(words):
    return random.choice(words)

def user_choice():
    return raw_input("Enter a random word: ")

def main():
    words = ["and", "that", "this", "is"]
    computer_generated_word = random_word(words)
    user_picked_word = user_choice()
    if computer_generated_word.lower() == user_picked_word.lower():
        print("Word has successfully been guessed '{}'...".format(computer_generated_word))
    else:
        print("That's not the right word...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now since you said you're new lets break this down for you..

```
import random
```

Import the `random` package, documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

```
def random_word(words):
    return random.choice(words)
```

Return a random word from a `list` of words given as a argument to the method using the built-in `random` package.

```
def user_choice():
    return raw_input("Enter a random word: ")
```

Create a method to get user input from `stdout` by calling the `raw_input` function (worth mentioning that it's just `input` after `2.7.x`)

```
def main():
    words = ["and", "that", "this", "is"]
    computer_generated_word = random_word(words)
    user_picked_word = user_choice()
    if computer_generated_word.lower() == user_picked_word.lower():
        print("Word has successfully been guessed '{}'...".format(computer_generated_word))
    else:
        print("That's not the right word...")
```

Create a main method to compare the two words lowercase version of eachother. If the words match, output they match, if not output they don't.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Python basic practice. Basically used to call the method you want when the program starts

```
    main()
```

Call the main method.