# How to run a Python script from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to make a GUI for an app I am making for my friend. It encodes a string. That is irrelevant though.
I need to use tkinter to make it so if you press a button it runs this code:

```
print "Welcome to the encoder"
print "[DO NOT USE CAPITAL LETTERS]"
# define the dictionary
encoder = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6", 
"g":"7", "h":"8", "i":"9", "j":"10", "k":"11", "l":"12", "m":"13", 
"n":"14", "o":"15", "p":"16", "q":"17", "r":"18", "s":"19", "t":"20", 
"u":"21", "v":"22", "w":"23", "x":"24", "y":"25", "z":"26"}

# take your input
Letter1 = raw_input ("Please input the first letter of the word: ")
Letter2 = raw_input ("Please input the second letter of the word: ")
Letter3 = raw_input ("Please input the third letter of the word: ")
Letter4 = raw_input ("Please input the fourth letter of the word: ")
Letter5 = raw_input ("Please input the fifth letter of the word: ")
Letter6 = raw_input ("Please input the sixth letter of the word: ")
Letter7 = raw_input ("Please input the seventh letter of the word: ")
Letter8 = raw_input ("Please input the eigth letter of the word: ")
Letter9 = raw_input ("Please input the ninth letter of the word: ")
Letter10 = raw_input ("Please input the tenth letter of the word: ")
Letter11 = raw_input ("Please input the eleventh letter of the word: ")
Letter12 = raw_input ("Please input the twelvth letter of the word: ")

# print out the encoded version
print encoder[Letter3] + " " + encoder[Letter2] + " " + encoder[Letter1] + "  " + encoder[Letter6] + " " + encoder[Letter5] + " " + encoder[Letter4] + "  " + encoder[Letter9] + " " + encoder[Letter8] + " " + encoder[Letter7] + "  " + encoder[Letter12] + " " + encoder[Letter11] + " " + encoder[Letter10]
```

Comment: Where's the tkinter code? If you copy all this into a tkinter app, it'll run, but I assume you want GUI input rather than terminal input?

Comment: Also, why not just "Please input a twelve letter word"?

Comment: @cricket_007 becuase I need each letter to be a variable

Comment: You can index a string to get individual characters...

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function

```
encoder = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4", "e":"5", "f":"6", 
"g":"7", "h":"8", "i":"9", "j":"10", "k":"11", "l":"12", "m":"13", 
"n":"14", "o":"15", "p":"16", "q":"17", "r":"18", "s":"19", "t":"20", 
"u":"21", "v":"22", "w":"23", "x":"24", "y":"25", "z":"26"}

def encode(letters):
    return " ".join(str(encoder.get(c, "")) for c in letters)
```

Then whatever tkinter code you write, call this function with either a list of letters or a lowercase string

[Taking input from the user in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495559/taking-input-from-the-user-in-tkinter)

For setting a tkinter label see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918054/2308683)

Comment: Yes, but my question was how to make the tkinter code

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please edit your question to include some attempt you've made. Then I'll update my answer

Comment: but i wasnt looking for the code given to me i was just looking for tips

Comment: That's hard to tell from your post. "Trying to make a GUI" sounds like you actually have tried something, but you didn't post it . Feel free to edit your question to rephrase