# Adding elements using Tkinter Dynamically

Tags: python, button, tkinter, dynamic, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create the program that has an add button, When it is clicked, several different elements like entries and buttons should appear on the output window. Firstly I am not able to structure the display correctly and secondly I am not sure as to how to get the values entered by the user in entry widget of Tkinter.
Here is the Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
lb = Tk()

def addentry():
    i = 3    // the 3 here should keep on incrementing so that the row goes on increasing as the user 
                keeps on adding different entries. This is for the display
    ent1 = Entry(lb, bd=5).grid(row =i ,column= 0)
    ent2 = Entry(lb, bd=5).grid(row = i, column=2)
    ent3 = Entry(lb, bd=5).grid(row = i, column=4)
    ent4 = Entry(lb, bd=5).grid(row = i , column=6)


addent = Button(lb, text = "Add Entry",command = addentry).grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Comment: Organise your tkinter app https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335

Comment: An simple exampel of using OOP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619867/layering-graphical-interfaces-on-top-of-each-other/62620295#62620295

Comment: OOP explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/13629335

Comment: get user input with tkinter https://stackoverflow.com/a/15495560/13629335

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do some research before asking. Also note that a good question is about a single issue. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Atlas435 Yes, I read other stack overflow questions related to my query but none of them were answering it. These 2 issues always arise together.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about keepin references. References are used to identify objects.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
my_entries = []
entry_row = 1
def addentry():
    global entry_row
    ent = tk.Entry(root, bd=5)
    ent.grid(row =entry_row ,column= 0)

    my_entries.append(ent)
    entry_row = entry_row+1

def getter():
    for entry in my_entries:
        my_stuff = entry.get()
        print(my_stuff)
    

addent = tk.Button(root, text = "Add Entry",command = addentry)
addent.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
getent = tk.Button(root,text='get input', command= getter)
getent.grid(row=0, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

In this exampel we keepin the references of the `tk.Entry` and the variable `entry_row` while we would like to work with later on. There are a bunch of solution for this. Here we had used a **global variable** and a **list** in the **global [namespace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-in-python-legb-rule/)** to access them.