# Creating a Caeser Cipher encryption in Python and Getting Errors

Tags: python, string, encryption

Q. Write a function called `shift_string` that takes a string and an integer `n` as parameters and returns a new string with every letter of the string shifted by the `n` alphabets. It should also work for negative alphabets in reverse order.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
usr_input=input('Please enter string: ')
n=input('enter shifts: ')
encryption= ""

def shift_string(usr_input,n):
    for i in usr_input:
        if i.isupper():
            i_unicode=ord(i) #find position
            
            i_index=i_unicode-ord('A')
            
            new_index= (i_index + n)
            
            new_unicode= new_index +ord('A') #to perform shift
            
            new_character=chr(new_unicode)
            encryption= encryption+new_character #to append string
        else:
            encryption=encryption+i #for non-uppercase
print('Encrypted text is',encryption)
```

`At encryption= encryption+new_character` I am getting the error:

*"Local variable 'encryption' defined in enclosing scope on line 23 referenced before assignment...(pyflakes E)"*

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You get one question per post.

Comment: Your last paragraph is quite out of scope here.  "I'm stuck" is not a Stack Overflow issue.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the second error; you never call the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python overwriting variables in nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935966/python-overwriting-variables-in-nested-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n=input(eval('enter shifts: '))
```

The argument to `eval()` has to be a string containing a Python expression. `enter shifts` is not a valid expression, you can't evaluate it. I suspect you meant `eval(input('enter shifts: '))`.

But you shouldn't use `eval()` to process user input. If you want to convert the input to a number, use `int()` or `float()`.

```
n = int(input('enter shifts: '))
```

The second error is because `encryption` is a local variable in the function, and you're trying to add to it before you've initialized it. You need to move `encryption = ""` inside the function. Then you can return the value.

```
def shift_string(usr_input,n):
    encryption = ""
    for i in usr_input:
        if i.isupper():
            i_unicode=ord(i) #find position
            
            i_index=i_unicode-ord('A')
            
            new_index= (i_index + n)
            
            new_unicode= new_index +ord('A') #to perform shift
            
            new_character=chr(new_unicode)
            encryption= encryption+new_character #to append string
        else:
            encryption=encryption+i #for non-uppercase
    return encryption

encrypted = shift_string(usr_input, n)
print('Encrypted text is',encrypted)
```