# Python callback variable scope

Tags: python, matplotlib, scope

I have a function `fun()` that binds a callback `callback()` when a matplotlib figure is clicked. I want this callback to be able to access the variable space of `fun()` to make changes. How can I go about this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def callback(event):
    data = event.xdata

def fun():
    data = 0

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(np.random.rand(12), np.random.rand(12), 'go')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', callback)

    plt.show()
    return data

print fun()
```

Putting `data` in the `global` scope is not an acceptable solution. The function should be self-contained. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960910/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-on-key-in-fig-canvas-mpl-connectkey-press-event) would allow me to pass variables to `callback()`, but would not let me edit them.

Comment: Use a nested function (define your callback in the body of fun). But notice that the fun function would already have terminated when your callback will be called.

Comment: I've already tried a nested function within ```fun()```: it does not work. A nested ```callback()``` can access the scope of ```fun()```, but it cannot modify it. Try it for yourself. Also, normally the function does not terminate until ```plt.show()``` is resolved (i.e. after canvas interaction). I have no issues with premature termination in the script above.

Comment: In fact you can by using a litte trick.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198709/how-do-i-change-nesting-functions-variable-in-the-nested-function.  You can use a dict, like d = dict(data=0) and then modify d["data"] in the nested function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you would like to have some state, that can be changed during runtime. One option might be to use a callable object, that is not a function (I have not tested it):

```
class Callback(object):
     def __init__(self, data):
         self.data = data
     def __call__(self, event):
         # Manipulate the data
         self.data += 1
...
datacallback = Callback(0)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', datacallback)
print datacallback.data
```

That way we would have a counter how often the event is raised. But it works with any kind of data, also more complex than an integer.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works. This solves my problem.